# How to convert from long to wide when some ID values are blank?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:

```
itemnum <- c("E1", "", "A", "", "A1a", "", "A2a", "A", "A2", "A", "B", "A", "", "")
substance <- c("ACETAMINOPHEN", "CAFFEINE", "ACETYL FENTANYL", "FENTANYL", "ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE", "COCAINE", "ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE", "AMPHETAMINE", "AMPHETAMINE", "AMPHETAMINE", "CAFFEINE", "FENTANYL", "HEROIN", "ACETYL FENTANYL")
qty <- c(0.000, "NA", 0.089, "NA", 5.151, "NA", 0.276, 0.714, 0.343, 0.948, 0.324, 1.181, "NA", "NA")
month_year <- c("2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01")
df <- data.frame(itemnum, substance, qty, month_year)
```

The blanks in itemnum indicate additional substances found in the same itemnum. I want each row to be an individual itemnum, with all substances found in that item spread out in additional columns, like this:

```
itemnum    substance                substance2       substance3        qty     month_year
E1         ACETAMINOPHEN            CAFFEINE                           0       2021-01
A          ACETYL FENTANYL          FENTANYL                           0.089   2021-01
A1a        ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE    COCAINE                            5.151   2021-01
A2a        ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE                                       0.276   2021-01
A          AMPHETAMINE                                                 0.714   2021-01
A2         AMPHETAMINE                                                 0.343   2021-01
A          AMPHETAMINE                                                 0.948   2021-01
B          CAFFEINE                                                    0.324   2021-01
A          FENTANYL                 HEROIN           ACETYL FENTANYL   1.181   2021-01
```

I'm familiar with long to wide in R, but I'm not sure how to do it in this case.  Is there a way to accomplish this easily in R?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the challenge here is due to the initial state of the data (no ID, blanks for `itemnum` and `qty` instead of repeating on each row), but here's a relatively simply `tidyverse` solution:

```
df |> 
  ## add unique id for each item
  mutate(item_id = if_else(itemnum != "", 1, 0),
         item_id = cumsum(item_id),
         itemnum = na_if(itemnum, ""),
         qty = na_if(qty, "NA")) |> 
  fill(c(itemnum, qty), .direction="down") |> 
  ## reshape data
  group_by(item_id) |> 
  mutate(substance_num = paste0("substance", row_number())) |> 
  select(item_id, itemnum, qty, month_year, substance_num, substance) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "substance_num", values_from = "substance")
```

## Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   item_id [9]
  item_id itemnum qty   month_year substance1            substance2 substance3     
    <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>                 <chr>      <chr>          
1       1 E1      0     2021-01    ACETAMINOPHEN         CAFFEINE   NA             
2       2 A       0.089 2021-01    ACETYL FENTANYL       FENTANYL   NA             
3       3 A1a     5.151 2021-01    ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE COCAINE    NA             
4       4 A2a     0.276 2021-01    ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE NA         NA             
5       5 A       0.714 2021-01    AMPHETAMINE           NA         NA             
6       6 A2      0.343 2021-01    AMPHETAMINE           NA         NA             
7       7 A       0.948 2021-01    AMPHETAMINE           NA         NA             
8       8 B       0.324 2021-01    CAFFEINE              NA         NA             
9       9 A       1.181 2021-01    FENTANYL              HEROIN     ACETYL FENTANYL
```

Comment: thanks! I will check this out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

itemnum <- c("E1", "", "A", "", "A1a", "", "A2a", "A", "A2", "A", "B", "A", "", "")
substance <- c("ACETAMINOPHEN", "CAFFEINE", "ACETYL FENTANYL", "FENTANYL", "ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE", "COCAINE", "ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE", "AMPHETAMINE", "AMPHETAMINE", "AMPHETAMINE", "CAFFEINE", "FENTANYL", "HEROIN", "ACETYL FENTANYL")
qty <- c(0.000, "NA", 0.089, "NA", 5.151, "NA", 0.276, 0.714, 0.343, 0.948, 0.324, 1.181, "NA", "NA")
month_year <- c("2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01", "2021-01")
df <- data.frame(itemnum, substance, qty, month_year)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(.x=="" | .x=="NA",NA,.x))) %>% 
  fill(c(itemnum,qty)) %>% 
  mutate(aux=data.table::rleid(itemnum)) %>% 
  group_by(aux) %>% 
  mutate(aux1 = paste0("substance",1:n())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(c(itemnum,qty,aux,month_year), 
              names_from = aux1, values_from = substance) %>% 
  fill(starts_with("substance"),.direction = "downup") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-aux) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  relocate(c(qty,month_year),.after=ncol(.))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 6
#>   itemnum substance1            substance2 substance3      qty   month_year
#>   <chr>   <chr>                 <chr>      <chr>           <chr> <chr>     
#> 1 E1      ACETAMINOPHEN         CAFFEINE   <NA>            0     2021-01   
#> 2 A       ACETYL FENTANYL       FENTANYL   <NA>            0.089 2021-01   
#> 3 A1a     ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE COCAINE    <NA>            5.151 2021-01   
#> 4 A2a     ACETYLMETHAMPHETAMINE <NA>       <NA>            0.276 2021-01   
#> 5 A       AMPHETAMINE           <NA>       <NA>            0.714 2021-01   
#> 6 A2      AMPHETAMINE           <NA>       <NA>            0.343 2021-01   
#> 7 A       AMPHETAMINE           <NA>       <NA>            0.948 2021-01   
#> 8 B       CAFFEINE              <NA>       <NA>            0.324 2021-01   
#> 9 A       FENTANYL              HEROIN     ACETYL FENTANYL 1.181 2021-01
```